# Vim isnt highlighting basic types in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, vim, syntax-highlighting

I have recently started using vim and i see my syntax files are located in /usr/share/vim/vim74 (I'm on linux Mint) and my c.vim seems to make the basic things like `int` and `double` keywords however when I edit any c or c++ files none of the types are highlighted however some things like `const` are highlighted. I am not sure why this is happening. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What color scheme are you using?

Comment: Can you ensure the following three things. 1) Make sure that the file /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/cpp.vim exists. 2) Make sure that /usr/share/vim/vimrc has the entry that says 'syntax on'. 3) Also make sure that no vimrc file such as ~/.vimrc has entry to switch off the syntax something like 'syntax off'.

Comment: 4)try to  add `filetype plugin indent on` and   
`syntax enable on` to ~/.virmrc

Comment: I am using a monokai theme downlaoded at https://github.com/sickill/vim-monokai

Comment: Yeah I figured out it was the color scheme that was doing it. I had to figure out whether or not the types were actually being recognized as keywords (and it was) and then go through my color scheme more closely to see how it was highlighting, and as it turns out the theme underlines the types, for some odd reason, in a dark background so it was essentially invisible  so i just changed it to highlight instead and it all works now. Thanks for the replies! this is my first time posting to stack overflow and was incredibly helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether the syntax parsing works as expected, check (when editing a C / C++ file) with

```
:syntax list
```

that those keywords (like `int`) are defined. You'll also get a preview of the highlight coloring there. Alternatively, the colors are shown via

```
:highlight
```

To change those, you have to switch to another `:colorscheme` or edit / augment the current one.

For advanced troubleshooting, I recommend the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin.

Comment: Thanks! your reply and the comments helped me figure out it was from downloading a theme off of github which for some reason did not highlight Type keywords. I used the highlight commands to determine how it was highlighting the keywords and it turns out it was underlining them on a black background ( I would have posted a picture in the question but this is my first time posting to Stack overflow so I couldn't)